# Secure form login

Tags: php, html

I have created a login form which displays username and password which must be entered to access index.php i also have the authenticate.php which is required by index.php so the file cant be accessed without logging in. But i cannot get the form to actually log me in it just flashes and takes me back to login.php

my code:

login.php

```
<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"> 
<fieldset> 
<legend>Please login:</legend> 
<dl> 
<dt> 
  <label title="Username">Username:
  <input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="50" id="username" /> 
  </label> 
</dt> 
</dl> 
<dl> 
<dt> 
  <label title="Password">Password:
  <input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /> 
  </label> 
</dt> 
</dl> 
<dl> 
<dt> 
  <label title="Submit"> 
  <input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" /> 
  </label> 
</dt> 
</dl> 
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

Authenticate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION["loginid"]) || $_SESSION["loginid"] != 'true') {
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

but it doesn't log in. ( please be aware I am quite new to PHP and am still learning ) I read somewhere i need a login_exec.php script which makes it login but everything i tried just crashed the site with an error.

Comment: You haven't got any code which so much as glances at the submitted form data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value to $_SESSION variable upon successful authentication

Like this

```
$_SESSION["loginid"] = $user_id;
```

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit scruffy, but the main issue is that you haven't changed the `action` attribute in the form to the page.

You will want to change `action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"` to `action="Authenticate.php"`. This will "Submit" the form to that page.

Do bear in mind that you haven't given us any information on databases, as well as that you will also want to look into user validation. Not to mention you haven't created any sessions inside of `Authenticate.php` as the user Shital suggested.